# How to fetch test category in test setup method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Below is code where test setup method is link with same namespace and all other unit test cases are applied. I want to skip particular unit test case to call test setup method. To achive that, applied `category` attribute but, its not able to fetch in `setup` method and all time giving 0 value for `Properties['_CATEGORIES']`.

```
    class 1
   {
    [Setup]
    public void SetupMethod()
    {
      if (CheckForSkipSetup()) return;
         ...
    }
    private static bool CheckForSkipSetup() {
        ArrayList categories = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test
           .Properties["_CATEGORIES"] as ArrayList;

        bool skipSetup = categories != null && categories.Contains( SKIP_SETUP );
        return skipSetup ;
    }
   } 
    class 2
    [Test]
    [Category("skipMethod")]
    public void Method1()
    {
    }
```

How to resolve this issue so, i can get category attribute in setup class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of NUnit 3, it is fixed there. The property key is `Category`.

For example, the following code,

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var cats = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test?.Properties["Category"];
    foreach (var cat in cats)
    {
        TestContext.WriteLine("Category: " + cat);
    }
}

[Test]
[Category("One")]
[Category("Two")]
public void TestMethod()
{
    Assert.Pass("Passes");
}
```

Produces the output,

```
Category: One
Category: Two
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in NUnit 2 without upgrading to NUnit 3. You can use the property of `TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest`.

For example

```cs
class 1 {

  [Setup]
  public void SetupMethod() {
    if (NUnit.Core.TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.Categories.Contains(SKIP_SETUP)) {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```